# Creating a table in MariaDB using a list of column names in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a table in mariadb using python. I have all the column names stored in a list as shown below.

`collist = ['RR', 'ABPm', 'ABPs', 'ABPd', 'HR', 'SPO']`

This is just the sample list. Actual list has 200 items in the list. I am trying to create a table using the above collist elements as columns and the datatype for the columns is VARCHAR.

This is the code I am using to create a table

`for p in collist:
     cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 ({} VARCHAR(45))'.format(p)`

The above code is executing but only the first element of the list is being added as a column in the table and I cannot see the remaining elements. I'd really appreciate if I can get a help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the string in 3 parts and then `.join()` those together. The middle portion is the column definitions, joining each of the item in the original list. This doesn't seem particularly healthy; both in the number of columns and the fact that everything is VARCHAR(45) but that's your decision:

```
collist = ['RR', 'ABPm', 'ABPs', 'ABPd', 'HR', 'SPO']

query = ''.join(["(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 ",
                ' VARCHAR(45), '.join(collist),
                ' VARCHAR(45))'])
```

Because we used `join`, you need to specify the last column type separately (the third item in the list) to correctly close the query.

**NOTE:** If the input data comes from user input then this would be susceptible to SQL injection since you are just formatting unknown strings in, to be executed. I am assuming the list of column names is internal to your program.

Comment: The downside is when `collist` is user controlled it might be very possible to inject other SQL statements.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That cannot really be avoided. You cannot escape column names with parameterization, and you have no schema to compare with to see whether the input was legitimate. I'm not sure I see a use-case where someone enters 200 column names by hand, though

Comment: @RaymondNijland Since I bang on about SQL injection all the time, I guess I should add a notice to my answer; I had assumed this was internal. MySQL is your tag, though, so I'd be interested to know if there was a safer method without doing the whole thing manually :)

Comment: "You cannot escape column names with parameterization," True a workaround for SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE queries would be to query `information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = <prepared_value>` and use that selected result into a dynamic query.. `information_schema.TABLES` contains safe data.

Comment: "MySQL is your tag, though, so I'd be interested to know if there was a safer method without doing the whole thing manually " Let me think about it..

Comment: @RaymondNijland but this is a CREATE, so there is no schema?

Comment: "but this is a CREATE, so there is no schema?" i know that's why i said `SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE queries` on your " You cannot escape column names with parameterization," comment

Comment: Check [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/18), this looks to be a pretty promising method, it past mine SQL injection tests so far.  which did include using ['BB;' with "sanity check"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/21) and [without](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/23) and ['BB OR 1 = 1' with "sanity" check](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/25) and [without](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/26).. Besides your live application should not print errors when live, yes it errors which is not injected.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You should post as an answer, mate, you've done the work here!